# Does Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>() allocate objects on managed heap?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, heap-memory, marshalling

I'm trying to reduce the memory allocations to reuduce Garbage Collection time in my application.

When analyzing my application for memory allocations, the VS2022 Performance Profiler tells me that Marshal.StructureToPtr() performs allocations on the small object heap. Here is the output:

Function Name;  Allocations;    Bytes;  Module Name
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(T, int, bool); 925.378; 74.030.240; mscorlib
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(T); 1.250; 100.000; mscorlib

It shows that even the Method Marshal.SizeOf() seems to allocate memory, too! In fact, the garbage collections show, that the struct I pass to these methods are frequently garbage collected.

It's my understanding that the method Marshal.StructureToPtr() copies a structure to a memory address. The memory at this destination address must have been allocated before. This should not involve any managed memory allocations.

My questions:

1. Is it true that these marhalling perform managed memory allocations that cause garbage collection?
2. If 1), I would like to understand why.
3. If 1), is there any way to avoid this to reduce garbage collection time?

Here is the context in which I use these methods:

```
        // Serialize only the first length elements of str
        public static byte[] ToBytes<T>(T[] str, int length)
        {
            if (str == null || str.Length == 0)
            {
                return new byte[0];
            }

            int usedLength = Math.Min(str.Length, length);
            int elementSize = Marshal.SizeOf(str[0]);
            int size =  usedLength * elementSize;

            byte[] arr = new byte[size];

            GCHandle h = default(GCHandle);

            try
            {
                h = GCHandle.Alloc(arr, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                for (int i = 0; i < usedLength; i++)
                {
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(str[i], h.AddrOfPinnedObject() + i * elementSize, false);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (h.IsAllocated)
                {
                    h.Free();
                }
            }

            return arr;
        }
```

Comment: Regarding your call to `Marshal.SizeOf(str[0]);` - I think that will be calling `Marshal.SizeOf(Object)` which will box a struct (and allocate on the small object heap). What happens if you change that to `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()` ?